# How can i get an overview of UWP registered URIs and aliases?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to use the "URI style launching" for UWP apps (for example: [MS ToDo](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/microsoft-to-do-lists-tasks-reminders/9nblggh5r558?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab)) from a win32 Application, command line or UWP apps.

UWP has a specific shell URI-Schemas available to launch them.

For example you can press win+R and enter `ms-todo:` and MS ToDo will start.
Respectively open cmd and enter `start ms-todo:` and MS ToDo will start.

How can i get a list with all local available URIs?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

They are listed in `Settings > Apps > Default Apps > Choose default apps by protocol`

## Getting details for all apps with Powershell

```
$result = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@();

foreach ($appx in Get-AppxPackage)
{
    $location = $appx.InstallLocation
    $manifest = "$location\AppxManifest.xml"

    if($location -ne $null -and (Test-Path $manifest -PathType Leaf))
    {
        [xml]$xml = Get-Content $manifest

        $ns = new-object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
        $ns.AddNamespace("main", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10")
        $ns.AddNamespace("uap", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10")
        $ns.AddNamespace("uap3", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3")
        $ns.AddNamespace("uap5", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5")

        $uriElements = $xml.SelectNodes("//uap:Extension[@Category = 'windows.protocol']/uap:Protocol/@Name", $ns)
        $uris = $uriElements | select -ExpandProperty '#text'

        $appIds = $xml.SelectNodes("//main:Application/@Id", $ns) | select -ExpandProperty '#text'

        if ($appIds.Count -eq 0) {
            continue;
        }

        $aliases = $xml.SelectNodes("//main:Extensions/uap5:Extension[@Category = 'windows.appExecutionAlias']/uap5:AppExecutionAlias/uap5:ExecutionAlias/@Alias", $ns) | select -ExpandProperty '#text'

        #$result[$appx.Name] = $uris
        $tmp = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $tmp | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Name –Value "$($appx.Name)"
        $tmp | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name URIs –Value ($uris -join "`n")
        $tmp | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Aliases –Value ($aliases -join "`n")
        $tmp | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Package –Value "$($appx.PackageFamilyName)"
        $tmp | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name AppIds –Value ($appIds -join "`n")
        $tmp | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Folder –Value $appx.InstallLocation
        
        $null = $result.Add($tmp)
    }
}

$result | Sort-Object -Property Name | Out-GridView
```

**Result**
[image]

## The manual way for a single App:

I'm only aware of a slighly cumbersome manual way have to do do for every single app.

In this case "Microsoft.Todos"

Execute
`Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Todos`

[image: Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Todos]

Read Property "InstallationLocation"
`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Todos_2.27.32662.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`

Open AppxManifest.xml
`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Todos_2.27.32662.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml`

[image: AppxManifest.xml]

Look for protocol entries:

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
    <uap:Protocol Name="ms-to-do">
        <uap:DisplayName>ms-resource:app_name_ms_todo</uap:DisplayName>
    </uap:Protocol>
</uap:Extension>
<uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
    <uap:Protocol Name="ms-todo">
        <uap:DisplayName>ms-resource:app_name_ms_todo</uap:DisplayName>
    </uap:Protocol>
</uap:Extension>
```

As you can see "ms-to-do" and "ms-todo" are the associated URIs.